# How to implement google/other search engine search of visually selected text in evil mode (counsel-search of selected text)

Tags: evil, search, counsel

How can I define a command that searches the web for the evil visually selected text using google or some other search engine? `counsel-search` already does this if you insert a string, but how can I define a command to do this using the selected text? (I'm using Evil.)
[image]

Comment: Your text was ambiguous. Instead of *searching* the selected *text*, in Emacs, I think you're asking about searching the *web* **for** the selected text. If I misunderstand, please edit to make clear what you're asking. Thx.

Comment: This is not a command, but thanks to EWW, to search for a selected text on the web, you can do `M-s` `M-w` `&`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this function:

```lisp
(defun counsel-search-selected (start end)
  (interactive "r")
  (let ((region (buffer-substring-no-properties start end)))
    (counsel-search-action region)))
```

However, instead of search visual selected text. I prefer use `thing-at-point`: `M-x counsel-search` and press `M-n`.

Comment: Wow, that's neat, I have no idea what buffer-substring-no-properties is, but it does the job. 
Also haven't know about thing-at-point, how would you implement the command which takes automatically the first suggested string of thing-at-point and counsel search it on the web in one click?

Comment: `buffer-substring-no-properties` remove text properties (like color etc.). For automatically insert `thing-at-point` you can refer to https://with-emacs.com/posts/ui-hacks/execute-commands-like-marty-mcfly/ and https://github.com/seagle0128/.emacs.d/blob/master/lisp/init-ivy.el#L164-L218

Comment: @TianshuWang: you should look up the `r` specification for the `interactive` form.

Comment: @NickD Thank you, I have updated this function.